# How to integrate matplotlib fumction with QGraphicView?

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyqt4, pyqtgraph

I am developing a Desktop application using Qt Designer and PyQt4. I need to display a some figure with contour which in python could be done with matplotlib.pyplot.contourf. I want to display the result inside a QGraphicView object.

I am trying to do it by promoting the QGraphicView to a pygtgraph in Qt-Designer. If object name of QGraphicView is CNOPlot I have written

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
self.CNOPlot.plot(plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z,cmap=plt.cm.autumn, alpha=0.8))
```

It is giving output in separate window.
I want this is to be ploted inside CNOPlot.

Comment: Add a `QGraphicsScene` to your view and render your plot in the scene.

Comment: Thank you so much @C.Dip. Can you please give some example or any link to show how to do that.
I am completly new to it.

Comment: Ok I write a short answer

Comment: And also shall I not promote it to pyqtgraph ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a short example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4.Qt import Qt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

class MyView(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QGraphicsView.__init__(self)

        scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.scene = scene

        figure = Figure()
        axes = figure.gca()
        axes.set_title("title")
        axes.plot(plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z,cmap=plt.cm.autumn, alpha=0.8))
        canvas = FigureCanvas(figure)
        canvas.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 500)
        scene.addWidget(canvas)

        self.setScene(scene)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but it still is coming as a separate window and with following error trace:

AttributeError: QuadContourSet instance has no attribute '__float__'

Comment: `xx` and `yy` must be arrays of integers.

Comment: But as per the requirement they cannot be.